# Can't reliably check for Bluetooth availability

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to check if Bluetooth is available on a device. When I go to Android settings I can't see anything about Bluetooth. Probably it's not present. But there is an issue. I my app I call:

`getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);`

and it returns `true`! Then I call:

`mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();`

It returns some object which is not `null`. So I call:

`mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()`

And here is magic. Sometimes it returns `false` and sometimes I got an exception:

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 68)
E/BluetoothAdapter: android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
        at android.bluetooth.IBluetooth$Stub$Proxy.isEnabled(IBluetooth.java:806)
        at android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.isEnabled(BluetoothAdapter.java:610)
        at com.gn.app.BluetoothScannerActivity.onCreate(BluetoothScannerActivity.java:53)
```

So how can I check if bluetooth is available when `hasSystemFeature()` lies to me and `getDefaultAdapter()` returns some zombie object?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `hasSystemFeature()`, but you do need to know whether the Bluetooth service is available on the device.

Here is how you can check this:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothManagerCompat.getAdapter(context);

if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {

    if (mBluetoothAdapter.getState() == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON) {

        // Bluetooth service is available

    } else {

        // Bluetooth service is not available
    }
} else {
    // Bluetooth service is not enabled
}
```